# Defference in mcrypt(Blowfish) between PHP4.4.4 and PHP5.3.3

Tags: php, encryption

Our customer has a legacy system implemented base on PHP4.4.4 (mcrypt 2.2.x).
They are thinking of upgrading it into PHP5.3.3 (mcrypt 2.5.8).
The code bellow shows the results of `my_data` collectly in PHP4.4.4.

```
$my_data = "xfZ3ruQZ+Is=";  
   // the string of "xfZ3ruQZ+Is=" is generated by
   // base64_encode(mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,"my_key","my_data",MCRYPT_ENCRYPT)) 
   // in PHP4.4.4
$my_key = "my_key";
$my_data = base64_decode($my_data);
$c_data = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,$my_key,$my_data,MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
echo $c_data;
```

On the other hand, the same code show the result of `"Dz}｢ﾂ鞅"` (different string) in PHP5.3.3 (mcrypt 2.5.8).

It seems that the crypted data in PHP4.4.4  can not be decrypted in PHP5.3.3.

(Such data can be stored in a database.)

Are there any way to decrypt the crypted string `data("xfZ3ruQZ+Is=")` in PHP5.3.3?

I know the function of mcrypt_ecb is deprecated.

But there are so many crypted data which are crypted by `mcrypt_ecb(BLOWFISH)` functionality in PHP4.4.4 in the Oracle Database.
And our customer requires these data should be decrypted on PHP5.3.3 referring the legacy database without data manipulation.

Any idea would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Two issues: 1. Do not use Blowfish, it is no londer consider secure, use AES as does it's author. 2. It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: There is that he has to load the previous data, I think the data is that it is BLOWFISH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mcrypt_ecb` should not be used.
Should be used `mcrypt_decrypt`.

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH_COMPAT, $my_key, $my_data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the bug report bellow, there is MCRYPT_BLOWFISH_COMPAT mode.

It worked and fixed it.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18267

```
mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH_COMPAT,$my_key,$my_data,MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
```

Comment: This answer is the best solution for our situation.